# Could not load type System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager while using Quartz.net

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I've just started with Quartz.NET scheduler. I simply copied the code from https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/using-quartz.html to check the working.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    // construct a scheduler factory using defaults
    StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    // get a scheduler
    IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
    await scheduler.Start();

    // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
                .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
                .Build();

    // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 40 seconds
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(40)
                    .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

But I'm getting the below message even after adding `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` dll explicitly.

```
  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager in the System.TypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131522
  Message=Could not load type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager' from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
  Source=Quartz
  StackTrace:
   at Quartz.Util.Configuration.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.InitializeProperties(ILog logger, Boolean throwOnProblem)
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Initialize()
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<GetScheduler>d__69.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Scheduler.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext()
```

And this the directory structure of my solution.
[image]

Please someone suggest me how I can resolve this problem.

Comment: Do you have .NET Core app or .NET Standard? And the library is suppose to be used with which one? :)

Comment: Target framework of my project is .NET 5. "Quartz.NET supports .NET Core/netstandard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.1 and later." , as stated by official doc and ConfigurationManager dll is referred from this path ```system.configuration.configurationmanager.5.0.0.nupkg\lib\net461\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll```. Based on the version mentioned in the .nupkg file, it should support my solution's target framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DLL you are referencing `system.configuration.configurationmanager.5.0.0.nupkg\lib\net461\` is build for .NET version 4.6.1.

Unfortunately your application is targeted for .NET version 5 - which is based in **.NET Core** implementation, as stated in [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five).

Resolution should be either:

- referencing `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` to DLL version **.NET Core** or **.NET 5**.
- or changing your application's base to .NET Framework 4.6.2 and bigger (must be  **.NET FW**)